# Inconsistent Data Points in HighCharts Scatter Plot with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-functional-component, react-highcharts

Previousy, I was using line charts. but now, I want multiple data points on same X-Axis with tooltip, and according to HighCharts behaviour -

"In a line chart, by default, Highcharts will display the tooltip for the last data point when multiple data points share the same x-axis value."

In order to achieve this behaviour, I have converted my chart to 'Scatter'.

=> I have a scatter plot (data points connected with a series line). Page load consistently plots correctly, but updating with new series data brings unexpected data points in the graph.

**Expected behaviour :** Plot consistently when updating with new series data

**Actual behaviour :** Inconsistent data points show up depending on previous series data.

I have researched about this and found this links which shows this was the issue with HighCharts and a way to resolve the same:

1. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9184
2. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9037

But, I am not able to figured out how can i solve this with ReactJS. Here is my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9wsnd9?file=index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the suggested workaround with React, you need to get the chart instance and call `setData` on series. For example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = chartRef.current.chart;
    if (chart) {
      chart.series[0].setData(mainData, true, true, false);
    }
  }, [data]);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jiva32?file=index.js

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-get-a-chart-instance

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Marking answer as accepted.